# SQL error while inserting data in Derby DB

Tags: java, sql, derby

I am getting this:

> SQLDataException:"java.sql.SQLDataException: An attempt was made to get a data value of type 'VARBINARY' from a data value of type 'BLOB' at org.apache.derby.client.am.SQLExceptionFactory.getSQLException(Unknown Source) ~[derbyclient-10.12.1.1.jar:na]"

I would appreciate if anyone has insights on this.

Comment: Show use your Java code and the `create table` statement of the table.

Comment: Hello a_horse_with_no_name, thank you for your response. Issues is solved by @LOB annotation in DAO. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is issue is resolved after doing following:

```
@Basic
@Column(name = "PARSED_DATA")
@Lob
public byte[] getParsedData() {
    return parsedData;
}
```

Since, table column is BLOB type.This is only issue with Derby.