# java.sql.SQLDataException: An attempt was made to get a data value of type 'BOOLEAN' from type 'DATE'

Tags: java, prepared-statement, derby

When trying to add a new row to my Derby DB in Java, some magic does happen in the PreparedStatement and some of it goes wrong whenever I try to run the following line:

```
ps.setBoolean(12, isTelefone_whatsapp());
```

While [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35070659/sql-error-while-inserting-data-in-derby-db) doesn't get me anywhere, I'm desperately asking for your help again!

`isTelefone_whatsapp()` looks like this:

```
public boolean isTelefone_whatsapp() {
    return telefone_whatsapp;
}
```

And I am 100% sure that (see pic below) **the data type of the column is `BOOLEAN`.**
I had the query autogenerated by NetBeans, so it should't contain any errors either.

[image: Proof of BOOLEAN being the data type of the column WHATSAPP]

**The same happens** if I comment this with one a couple lines down. There I'm trying to set a Long, which is for sure an `BIGINT` in the database and the method I'm using does for sure return a `Long`.

I mean I don't even **understand** why it is looking for 'DATE'?!? Does anyone have an **idea** and even more important: **A Fix?**

Thanks in advance!

Here is some more (important!) information:

This is the query I use to create the PreparedStatement:

```
String query = "INSERT INTO LSV_ADMIN.MEMBERS "
            + "(ID, MEMBER_STATUS, \"NAME\", PRENAME, STREET, ZIP_CODE, CITY, PHONE_PRIV, "
            +" PHONE_WORK, PHONE_FAX, PHONE_MOBILE, WHATSAPP, "
            + "E_MAIL, BIRTHDAY, LVB_ID, MALE, PRIMARY_MEMBER, "
            + "MEMBER_TYPE, PRIMARY_BRANCH, SECONDARY_BRANCHES, "
            + "ENTRY, \"EXIT\", "
            + "CHANGE_TO_ACTIVE, CHANGE_TO_SUPPORTIVE, MEDICAL, INVITE_TO_PARTY, "
            + "STATUS_GLIDER_PILOT, STATUS_MOTORGLIDER_PILOT, "
            + "STATUS_ULTRALIGHT_PILOT, STATUS_HANGGLIDER_PILOT, STATUS_MOTOR_PILOT, "
            + "STATUS_BALLOON_PILOT, STATUS_WINCH_DRIVER, "
            + "STATUS_UNICOM_OP, FEE_DISCOUNT, DEATH, FUNCT,STATUS_HELICOPTER_PILOT) \n"
            + " VALUES (?, ?, '?', '?', '?', ?, '?', '?', '?', '?', "
            + " '?', ?, '?', ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?,"
            + " ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)\n";
```

Here is some trace if anyone feels like reading a novel:

```
t org.apache.derby.client.am.SQLExceptionFactory.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.client.am.SqlException.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.client.am.ClientPreparedStatement.setBoolean(Unknown Source)
at data.Member.insertIntoStatement(Member.java:416)
at lsv_verwaltung.MitgliederController.importMembers(MitgliederController.java:705)
at lsv_verwaltung.MitgliederController.openImportMembersDialoge(MitgliederController.java:679)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:71)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:275)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1769)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1657)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
at javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8411)
at javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Button.java:185)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(ButtonBehavior.java:182)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:96)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:89)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3757)
at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Scene.java:3485)
at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1762)
at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2494)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:380)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:294)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$354(GlassViewEventHandler.java:416)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:389)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:415)
at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:555)
at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:937)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$148(WinApplication.java:191)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: The SQL when you create the prepared statement is very important information for the fix.

Comment: Oh sure, I'm sorry, give me a sec

Comment: @LukeLee There you go, thanks for the heads up!

Comment: The error message is itself the answer to your question. It appears you believe the column is of type Boolean but is really Date, or your method `isTelefone_whatsapp()` is returning a Date rather than a Boolean. The [Answer by Luke Lee](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38112568/642706) is probably correct. Please edit your Question after you verify the ***exact*** data type of the column and of the method signature’s return value.

Comment: I'm sorry, it was late last night. Thought I'd give this question a chance over night which apparently didn't work due this lack of information. Now it is there though, and I have to disappoint you, but the datatypes are correct. That was the first thing I checked because that is basically as you said exactly what the error messages suggest.

Comment: Another thing is that you are using single-quoted `'?'` for place holders, you don't need them and they may be messing with the index.

Comment: And the winner is: @LukeLee, thanks a lot that's exactly what went wrong there! I thought I better not mess with what NetBeans spilled out... I will think again next time :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `?` fills in its own quotes when needed. You introduced strings with as content a question mark. So remove the quotes around them.

This caused the numbering of placeholder ?s to go wrong, and arrive at some SQL DATE column.

Comment: Jupp, that did the trick. Now I'm just left wondering why NetBeans gave me this query...

Answer (score 1):

Pretty sure the problem is that the `WHATSAPP` column or any column at index 12 has data type `DATE`.

The problem with this kind of prepared statement is that it's very hard for humans to notice which column is at index 12. I counted and it seems to be the WHATSAPP column, but maybe the database don't think so. I suggest you try to insert this one column first and see what you get.

The following observation comes from reading the derby client code.

If you have the derby client source code, you can see that the exception is thrown by this method:

```
static SqlException throw22005Exception(...)
```

And `22005` can be found here [SQLState and error message reference](https://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.1/ref/rrefexcept71493.html)

> **22005** An attempt was made to get a data value of type '<typeName>' from a data value of type `
>   '<typeName>'.

Although you are setting instead of getting data, a shame the derby client code does not differentiate those cases.

Comment: Check my edit for the information I added please. The datatypes should be correct.